# More efficient way of iterative hashing

Tags: hash

Here is a possible way to perform iterative cryptographic hashing twice as fast as in the ordinary way.

Given a compression function $f: \{0,1\}^{a+b} \rightarrow \{0,1\}^b$. Assume the message is of length $4a$ bits after padding. Normally the four message blocks are injected one after another into a data block $x_i \in \{0,1\}^b$:

$$
m = m_0 \| m_1 \| m_2 \| m_3; \; |m_i| = a
$$
$$
x_{i+1} = f(x_i \| m_i); \; i=0,1,2,3; \; x_0 = IV
$$
$$
h = x_4
$$
A first idea to hash faster is to simplify the compression function, e. g. replace $f$ by a function $g$ that is built similarly but uses only $\frac 1 4$ of the internal rounds. Compute $x_4$ like above with using $g$ instead of $f$ and finalize by $h=p(x_4)$, where $p$ is a pseudorandom function that doesn't allow to compute $x_4$ from the hash $h$.

I reckon this might be secure against preimage but not collision attacks, because there is too much correlation between $x_i$ and $x_{i+1}$, allowing to construct message blocks $m_i, \overline m_i, m_{i+1}, \overline m_{i+1}$ so that
$$g(g(x_i\|m_i)\|m_{i+1})=g(g(x_i\|\overline m_i)\|\overline m_{i+1})$$
The idea is now to insert each message block twice:

$$
x_{i+1} = g(x_i \| m_{i \bmod 4}); \; i=0,...,7
$$
$$
h = x_8
$$
Now there are at least five calls to $g$ between the injections of two different blocks $m_i, m_j$. For example $m_2$ is hashed when $i=2$ and $m_3$ when $i=7$, thus there shouldn't be exploitable correlation between $x_2$ and $x_7$. Yet this scheme uses only $\frac 1 2$ the rounds in total, compared with the ordinary method.

Would this be secure, given the round number of $f$ is just sufficient to make the ordinary method secure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one obvious approach to try to find a collison:

- Search for a pair $m_1, \overline{m_1}$ with the property that $g(x \| m_1) = g(x \| \overline{m_1})$ for a nontrivial fraction of $x$.  Given that $g$ has a reduced number of rounds, this may be do-able.
- Now, start with a fixed $x_i$ (corresponding to a known message prefix), and search for an $m_0$ s.t. $g(x_i \| m_0)$ is one of the colliding preimages for $m_1, \overline{m_1}$.
- Call $g(g(x_0 \| m_0) \| m_1)$ the value $x_2$; search for an $m_2, m_3$ pair such that $g(g(g(x_2 \| m_2) \| m_3) \| m_0)$ is also a colliding pair.

If we can find that, then the message blocks $(m_0, m_1, m_2, m_3)$ and $(m_0, \overline{m_1}, m_2, m_3$) collide when added to the message prefix.

How doable is this?  That depends on how feasible the first step is (and how probable a random $x$ value is a colliding preimage) - if we can get the probability of a colliding preimage up to $2^{-N}$, then the amount of effort used by the remaining steps is an expected $2^{N+1}$ work...

Comment: This attack can be hampered by entering the iteration number into each compression step: $x_{i+1}=g(x_i \| m_{i \bmod 4}, i)$.